# Any button to switch DOZE mode on, on Android studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Is there any button that i can click to switch DOZE mode on, on the android studio emulator?? I can't seem to find any way to manually switch it on.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze_and_app_standby:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```